# ORMLite query foreign key

Tags: android, database, foreign-keys, ormlite

I have 2 classes

List

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "loginsList")
public class LoginsList {

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "loginListID", generatedId = true)
    private int loginListID;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "listName")
    private String listName;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "listDescription")
    private String listDescription;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "current")
    private boolean current;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "sent")
    private boolean sent;
```

Login

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "login")
public class Login {
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "loginID", generatedId = true)
    private int loginID;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "user", foreign=true)
    private User user;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "loggedIn")
    private boolean loggedIn;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "loginTime")
    private long loginTime;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "logoutTime")
    private long logoutTime;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "loginsList", foreign = true)
    private LoginsList loginsList;
```

I use ORMLite for the database. I want to know how can I get all logins for a list? I tried like this

```
tempLoginList = loginDao.queryForEq("loginsList", list);
```

where list is of type LoginsList and it is the list I want to get all the logins for, but it doesn't work. How to do it with query builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tempLoginList = loginDao.queryForEq("loginsList", list);
```

That should work fine.  Here's a couple things to check for that may be getting in the way.

- ORMLite stores an `int` in `Login` which is the `loginListID` field from the `LoginsList`.  When you associate a list with a `Login`, it must *already* have been created in the database so its id has already been generated.
- If you look at your query logs (turn on [logging](http://ormlite.com/docs/logging) with something like the following log4j properties, you should see the associated query.  You should be able to see the `login` id field being queried for.  You need to make sure that it is correct.

  ```
  log4j.logger.com.j256.ormlite=DEBUG
  # to enable logging of arguments to all of the SQL calls
  # uncomment the following lines
  log4j.logger.com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.BaseMappedStatement=TRACE
  #log4j.logger.com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate=TRACE
  #log4j.logger.com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor=TRACE
  ```

I have a lot of unit tests but not specifically around `dao.queryForEq(...)` and foreign fields.  I just added them to the code base and they work fine.  Here's my log output which might help:

```
[DEBUG] BaseMappedStatement insert data with statement 'INSERT INTO `foo` (`val` ,`equal` ,`null` ) VALUES (?,?,?)' and 3 args, changed 1 rows
[TRACE] BaseMappedStatement insert arguments: [1231231, 0, null]
[DEBUG] BaseMappedStatement assigned id '1' from keyholder to 'id' in Foo object
[DEBUG] BaseMappedStatement insert data with statement 'INSERT INTO `foreign` (`foo_id` ) VALUES (?)' and 1 args, changed 1 rows
[TRACE] BaseMappedStatement insert arguments: [1]
[DEBUG] BaseMappedStatement assigned id '1' from keyholder to 'id' in Foreign object
[DEBUG] StatementBuilder built statement SELECT * FROM `foreign` WHERE `foo_id` = 1 
[DEBUG] BaseMappedStatement prepared statement 'SELECT * FROM `foreign` WHERE `foo_id` = 1 ' with 0 args
[DEBUG] SelectIterator starting iterator @1781793025 for 'SELECT * FROM `foreign` WHERE `foo_id` = 1 '
[DEBUG] SelectIterator closed iterator @1781793025 after 1 rows
[DEBUG] StatementExecutor query of 'SELECT * FROM `foreign` WHERE `foo_id` = 1 ' returned 1 results
```